# Google Docs to feed text on website

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, dynamic, google-docs

Would like to figure out a way to load text from Google Docs into a div on a page... can use PHP, jQuery, whatever it takes.

I sort of found something for google sheets, sheetrock.js, but is there anything for Google Docs?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your document in public in "File" -> "Publish on the web" or something like that, then you will be able to access to your document with adding "/pub?embedded=true" at the end of your URL instead of "/edit".